# Django sign up view how to get the user from the user form to assign profile to the user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have this sign up form where I am taking values from the user about his username and password and also his proile. I have separately created two forms `UserForm` and `ProfileForm`. When the user is signing up for his account how do I connect profile to the user.

This is what I have

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                         label='Email',
                         error_messages={'exists': 'Oops'})
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
            # user.status = self.cleaned_data["status"]
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['contact', 'whatsapp', 'gender', 'avatar']
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Permanent")),
    (2, ("Temporary")),
    (3, ("Contractor")),
    (4, ("Intern"))
    )
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Male")),
    (2, ("Female")),
    (3, ("Not Specified"))
    )
    PAY_CHOICES = (
    (1, ("Fixed")),
    (2, ("Performance Based")),
    (3, ("Not Assigned")),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_type = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    whatsapp = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=3)
    pay_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PAY_CHOICES, default=3)
    pay = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/images', default='users/images/default.jpg')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=False)
    #manager_username = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, to_field='username',related_name='manager_username', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def createAccount(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        u_form = SignUpForm(request.POST) # fill it with user details
        p_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            profile = p_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = u_form.user
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account Updated')
            return redirect('createAccount')
    return render(request, 'mainapp/createAccount.html')
```

When I am creating a new user with his profile information. I am getting an error

```
AttributeError at /create
'SignUpForm' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/create
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'SignUpForm' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\Desktop\ATG IInternship\INTRANET\atg-intranet\Intranet\users\views.py in createAccount, line 23
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Himanshu Poddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.2
```

I think this is the part where I am going wrong, My question is how do I connect the user to his profile while signing up.

```
u_form.save()
profile = p_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = u_form.user
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: That `save` method on SignupForm is a) unnecessary because the modelform will already set the email value and b) not even called because it is indented within Meta. You should delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile.user = u_form.user` is indeed causing problems here.

You try to access the user created by the `SignupForm`, but it is not set as a property of the form, but returned by the `save` method.

To fix this, you'll need to capture the user created by the SignUpForms's save method. Change the block where you create the user and profile to this:

```
...
user = u_form.save()
profile = p_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
...
```

Comment: Now I am getting `IntegrityError at /create
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_profile.user_id` can you tell me why, I even deleted all my migrations and started again

Comment: You're getting that because your signal already creates a Profile. Remove that signal.

Comment: ok, but the problem is even that is required because acording to the logic, this page is only accessible to few of the user and the manager should be able to create their account from the django admin page for them the profile should be created automatically